# Zend +/- buttons to increase or decrease value

Tags: php, zend-framework

I currently have a Zend form where you add data into a number field. But I want to add 2 buttons where you can increase or decrease the value then Submit the data.

Current code :

```
$this->add(array( 
    'name' => 'score_1',
    'type' => 'Number',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'PPV',
     ),
));
```

Is it possible to edit that code, or would I need to find another solution?

EDIT: My mistake, not radio buttons.

Comment: Why do you want to use radio buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is to create your own Form Element helper extends the Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormNumber helper.

You can modify the render, and add your +/- buttons (with javascript action to increase or decrease your element value) to erase the render() method.